# Question about cardinalities of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ be finite such that $\left |A\cap C \right|\ge \left |B\cap C \right|$. From this, can we conclude that $\left |\neg B\cap C \right|\ge \left |\neg A\cap C \right|$?

My gut feeling tells me that we can. Either $C$ is finite or not. If $C$ is finite, then the conclusion follows trivially. If $C$ is not finite, i.e. it is infinite, then $\left |\neg B\cap C \right|= \left |\neg A\cap C \right|$. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your $\neg B\cap C$ is equivalent to the set difference $C\setminus B$, your reasoning is correct assuming the axiom of choice.

In the absence of the axiom of choice it is consistent that $C$ be an [amorphous set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set), and in that case there is no bijection between $C\setminus B$ and $C\setminus A$ if $|A\cap C|>|B\cap C|$: such a bijection could be extended by a bijection between $B\cap C$ and a proper subset of $A\cap C$ to yield a bijection between $C$ and a proper subset of itself, and an amorphous set admits no such bijection.

However, in that case we can actually show that $|C\setminus A|<|C\setminus B|$. Let $A'=A\cap C$, $B'=B\cap C$, and $D=C\setminus(A'\cup B')$. Since $|A'|>|B'|$, $|A'\setminus B'|>|B'\setminus A'|$, and there is an injection $\varphi:B'\setminus A'\to A'\setminus B'$. Let

$$f:C\setminus A'\to C\setminus B':x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }x\in D\\
\varphi(x),&\text{if }x\in B'\setminus A'\,;
\end{cases}$$

then $f$ is an injection, so $|C\setminus A|<|C\setminus B|$.

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is finite, we have the following:

$|A \cap C| + |C - A| = |C|$ since $A \cap C$ and $C - A$ are disjoint sets whose union is $C$. Similarly, we have $|B \cap C| + |C - B| = |C|$. Thus, we have $|C - A| = |C| - |A \cap C| \leq |C| - |B \cap C| = |C - B|$.

If $C$ is infinite, we have $|C - B| = |C - A| = |C|$.

So yes, your analysis is correct.